# Why is this Visual Studio Code just running without giving output?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I am trying to make a reverse number program in C but when I try to run in VSCode the code is running and gives me no output, so I stop the code and it says `[Done] exited with code=1 in 122.844 seconds`.

By the way, there is no error if I just `printf("Hello World")`.

My code is:

```c
#include <stdio.h>  

int main() {    
    int n, reverse = 0, rem;    
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    while (n != 0) {    
        rem = n % 10;    
        reverse = reverse * 10 + rem;
        n /= 10;
    }    
    printf("Reversed Number: %d", reverse);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user3121023 I doubt that it helps. The description of final output and the observation of HelloWorld (without flush) does not match.

Comment: Have you reboot the computer?

Comment: Yeah fflush doesn't help and i rebbot my pc but no still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes assumptions on input.
With clean input it works.
Do not use `scanf()` for potentially unclean input, e.g. user input or from a possibly unclean project environment.
From your description it seems likely that there is no input at all, because you do not mention it and because you describe a waiting program.
Double check the input you intend to provide and the method.

Try executing the created executable from a shell/prompt (i.e. not via your IDE) and do provide input in integer syntax, then it will work.

Comment: But,when i try to use a different editor like online c compiler it works fine with same codes.

Comment: The online compiler implies a different setup of input and output. What you describe supports my interpretation of your problem. Did you try what I proposed?

Comment: Actually i didn't understand it completly.I make a clean project enviroment and try to use gets() not scanf() but doesn't help.

Comment: Please find the executable created by building your program. I.e. on windows probably "something.exe". Open a command prompt and execute your program there. `D:\StackOverflow\C\SOtoyC>a.exe`.

Comment: Now,in command prompt it says Enter Number:  after i enter some number it closes.

Comment: PS D:\VSCode> .\test.exe
Enter a number: 23
Reversed Number: 0  this is new why is output 0 ?

Comment: Please change code to init `int n=412, reverse=0, rem;`, rebuild and try again.

Comment: Please describe in more detail what you mean by "after i enter some number it closes".

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling the vs code and installing all libraries. Your code is working fine in my vs code. or you can try running it on cmd prompt.
Use-

```
gcc yourprogram.c
     ./yourprogram
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that the prompt `Enter a number:` is not flushed to the terminal (or whatever emulation VSCode uses) and you do not enter the integer to reverse but wait and finally kill the program. Most C libraries have a special behavior to avoid this problem: `stdout` is flushed whenever input is requested from `stdin`. You can force this by adding `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf()` call.

With this fix, the program should behave as expected.

Note however that you should check for successful conversion by `scanf()`: it returns the number of conversions, which should be `1` if the user entered a number.

Also print a trailing newline at the end of the program's output.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>  

int main() {    
    int n;
   
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    if (scanf("%d", &n) == 1) {
        int reverse = 0;
        while (n != 0) {    
            int rem = n % 10;    
            reverse = reverse * 10 + rem;
            n /= 10;
        }    
        printf("Reversed number: %d\n", reverse);
    }
    return 0;
}
```